# TextBox AutoCompleteType.Email not working in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, autocomplete

I've set my `TextBox` `AutoCompleteType` property to `AutoCompleteType.Email` it works fine in IE but nothing append in chrome or firefox.

It seems an attribute (`vcard_name="vCard.Email"`) is just rendered in IE. I want to know `vcard_name` is an attribute just for IE or not? and have another borwsers some attribute like `vcard_name`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers use the `name` attribute of fields (and sometimes their associated labels) to do autocompletion.  As long as your fields have relatively straightforward names ('email', 'firstname', etc.) most browsers should be able to find them.  However, the implementation details vary from browser to browser; I'm not sure there's any standard you can adhere to that will guarantee success in all cases.

Comment: Oh no, I can't set `name` attribute because this attribute is reserved by asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

`object:vcard_name` is only supported in IE. See [here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljwgvcmt.php#supByObj) for full support.

Comment: Thanks, but what about another browsers?

Comment: Probably going to be inconsistent across browsers. Check here for some more info: http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard-implementations